# Secure ASP.NET Web API call

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, https

What is the best and most simple way to secure Web API call? For example if we have client who is sending a username and password for authentication. If we send it like a plain text we are leaving doors open for hackers. Can someone maybe share tutorials about implementing HTTPS for this kind of scenario. I believe that for start making a call over HTTPS would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial for IIS: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis.

Also see this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api